# Increase the 'technologies list' character limit in the Developer Story's Position section

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, developer-story

In the developer story, in the position section there is a technologies list, which contains a tags limit of 300 characters.

[image]

Is it possible to increase this limit? It is impossible to add all the technologies used on my project in 300 characters.

Comment: Wut? Can't you use as many tags as you want?

Comment: No, you can't) String with tags separated by space must be less than 300 characters(((

Comment: @VladimirKovpak how many tags are you trying to add?

Comment: @bluefeet On 1st position I have 32 and on 2nd I have 36, and I'm not able to add 1 additional tag not to 1st nor to 2nd position.

Comment: Think of it as a challenge to be more concise. It's not just about how many you want to write, it's about how many people want to read. :-)

Comment: @VladimirKovpak You worked on 36 different technologies in one position?

Answer (score 3):

In the latest release, we increased the character limit on tags to 350 on the developer story.

We did a quick check and of the 3.6 million story items, only about 6000 items have more than 200 characters in the tags, so it is a relatively small number using any where near the 300.

Comment: Now I understand your questions... I didn't know these statistics...Now I understand that my request doesn't make sense... Thank you!

Comment: 3.6 million developer stories, wowzer!

Comment: @DavidG story items.

Comment: Ahh, are you allowed to share how many stories?

Comment: @DavidG Probably but I didn't query that. :)

Comment: Another time then, may be a fun blog subject. :)

Comment: @DavidG 1.2 million dev stories.

Comment: Still very impressive!

Comment: @bluefeet Just curious, does SO Dev-Stories use mysql db, varchar column to store these technologies list or something like that?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak We use SQL Server and they are stored in a nvarchar column.

Comment: @bluefeet In your answer, you've specified 350 characters, but I have this error about 300 characters: https://prnt.sc/gqgzl9 What does it mean?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak The database has been increased. I've pinged a dev about it though.

Comment: @bluefeet But I still receive error about 300 characters.

Comment: @VladimirKovpak Yeah, I've poked a dev to look into it.